# C++/Win32 API - SetFocus to button does not work

Tags: c++, api, winapi, button, setfocus

```
HWND button = CreateWindowEx(0, "BUTTON", ...);
SetFocus(button); // Button no get focus! :(
```

Also, I have other controls on my form that I am able to SetFocus() to.

Thanks, Martin

Comment: nope, window and button created at runtime using createwindowex

Comment: How do you verify that it doesn't have the focus? What does `GetFocus` return, if not `button`?

Answer (score 3):

It has been FOREVER since I've had to do this, but...

Were this a dialog, I would tell you to send a WM_NEXTDLGCTL via PostMessage(). The default dialog item message handler would take care of the rest for you setting keyboard focus and selection activation. However, this is a different case if I read this correctly. You're creating both parent and child windows raw on the fly. If this is the case, SetFocus() to the parent window, and  handle WM_SETFOCUS on the parent window by bringing it to top, then setting focus on the child window. WM_SETFOCUS, and WM_KILLFOCUS  were designed to allow you to switch the 'activated' state of your controls, and most handle it for you (unless your window is an owner draw control or some such). But in a raw window, when your base parent window is sent the focus, you need to appropriately ensure the proper child has it if you're hosting any (think of it as managing your own 'dialog'). Again, normally this is done by the default dialog procedure for you if this were a dialog, but being raw windows you're kind of stuck managing it all yourself.

Though I can't imagine how, I hope that helped somewhat.

Comment: It seems that `WM_NEXTDLGCTL` works fine with `SendMessage` too.

Answer (score 0):

SetFocus is a function, not a procedure.  Call it as a function and check its returned value.  Either the retuned value is null because you made an error in the CreateWindowEx() call and "button" isn't a valid handle or it's a window not associated with your thread's message queue, or the return value is not null (it's now the prior focused window's handle) and you do have the focus (but are somehow failing to detect it).

Comment: What's the difference between a function and a procedure? As far as I can see (I may be wrong), I am calling it as a function. In my code, I'm checking to see if SetFocus returns NULL and if the button's handle is NULL. They aren't. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: btw, I can setfocus to other controls on my window

Comment: @Martin: a function call has a return value, like CreateWindowEx(). The correct SetFocus() call would be oldhandle = SetFocus(newhandle). You should be checking the button value returned by CreateWindowEx() to determine if that call is returning a non-null.  You say you are, so your actual code must be different than what you posted.  Post the complete code, including how you are determining you don't have the focus (because maybe you do).  Also note that SetFocus() sends WM_KILLFOCUS and WM_SETFOCUS messages to the formerly and currently focused windows.

Comment: ok the button gets the focus but, the border you get when you "tab" to the button is not there

Comment: @Martin: The style param (3rd param for CreateWindow, 4th param for CreateWindowEx) should include WS_TABSTOP to get the focus after a tab.

Comment: @Martin: You probably need to set the `BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON` style (and to remove it from any button that had the style before).  Normally you shouldn't be doing this yourself and should be using something like `WM_NEXTDLGCTL` if you're using a dialog box. (Also see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/02/205624.aspx .)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `WS_TABSTOP` style on the button.

Answer (score 0):

If you create that button in respond of the WM_INITDIALOG message you should return FALSE to prevent dialog box procedure to change the focus.